# AngularJS Two Way Binding Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, directive

I am working on a project which requires the use of a directive, I had my directive working binding to ngModel but I realized I need to bind multiple values, when I changed my code to bind value and staticValue the scope variable assigned to this is now undefined. Below is my code,

```
var app = angular.module('fieldSelectCheck', []);
app.directive('fieldSelectCheck', function () {

    var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.checkBoxClick = function () {
            if ($scope.isChecked === true) {
                $scope.fieldToggle = true;
            } else {
                $scope.fieldToggle = false;
                $scope.staticValue = "";
            }
        };

    }],

    url = 'Custom/BSI_iMIS_Importer/App/Directives/fieldSelectCheck.html';

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: url,
        scope: {
            fieldName: '@',
            fieldText: '@',
            options: '=',
            checkBoxClick: '@',
            isChecked: '@',
            fieldToggle: '=?bind',
            value: '=',
            staticValue: '='
        }, 
        controller: controller
    };
});
```

HTML Template

```
<div class="form-group row" data-ng-app="app">
    <label for="{{fieldName}}" class="col-lg-2 form-control-label text-right">{{fieldText}}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3" data-ng-hide="fieldToggle">
        <select class="form-control" name="{{fieldName}}" data-ng-model="value" data-ng-options="option for option in options">
            <option value="">-- Please Select A Field --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" data-ng-show="fieldToggle">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="staticValue" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="isChecked" data-ng-change="checkBoxClick()" /> Static Value
    </div>
</div>
```

Implementation of Directive

```
<field-Select-Check 
    field-Name="{{fields}}" 
    field-Text="{{fields}}" 
    value="test" 
    static-Value="$parent[fields].staticValue"
    options="userFields"
    ng-repeat="fields in nameFields">
</field-Select-Check>
```

Comment: I think scope inside directive goes without '$', so var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) { should be var controller = ['scope', function (scope) {

Comment: I don't think that is the issue I tried that and it broke my checkbox functionality that part of the code is working fine it just the two-way binding.

Comment: where do you get undefined? You need to show us the directive template or make a fiddle that reproduces your error.

Comment: Don't use `value` as a custom attribute name. That attribute name is already in use by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate custom directive from the `ng-repeat` directive. The custom directive creates isolate scopes. The `ng-repeat` directive expects inherited scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="fields in nameFields">
    <field-select-check 
        field-name="{{fields}}" 
        field-next="{{fields}}" 
        value="test" 
        static-value="valueList[fields]"
        options="userFields">
    </field-Select-Check>
</div>
```